# Using regex to find arbitrary length consecutive blocks

Tags: regex, algorithm, pattern-matching

I have a string containing ones and zeroes. I want to determine if there are substrings of 1 or more characters that are repeated at least 3 consecutive times. For example, the string '000' has a length 1 substring consisting of a single zero character that is repeated 3 times. The string '010010010011' actually has 3 such substrings that each are repeated 3 times ('010', '001', and '100').

Is there a regex expression that can find these repeating patterns without knowing either the specific pattern or the pattern's length? I don't care what the pattern is nor what its length is, only that the string contains a 3-peat pattern.

Comment: I don't believe what you're describing can be represented with regular expressions.

Comment: perhaps something like this? @"(.*[01][01][01].*)\{3\}"

Comment: @DanFego, regex (in this context) are not regular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(.+)\1\1
```

The `\` might be a different charactor depending on your language choice.  This means match any string then try to match it again twice more.

The `\1` means repeat the 1st match.

Comment: Argggg! I actually tried this pattern in python but it didn't work. After reading the answers here, I went back and tried it again, realizing that I used the wrong expression for the captured value. In python, it becomes '(.+)\\1\\1'.

Comment: EDIT, I changed the $ to a \ because it is more common. And obviously it needs to be escaped as per your language. Probably \\

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that might work, however, it will only tell you if there is *a* pattern repeated three times, and (I don't think) can't be extended to tell you if there are others:

```
     /(.+).*?\1.*?\1/
```

Breaking that out:

```
   (.+)          matches any 1 or more characters, starting anywhere in the string
   .*?           allows any length of interposing other characters (0 or more)
   \1            matches whatever was captured by the (...+) parentheses
   .*?           0 or more of anything
   \1            the original pattern, again
```

If you want the repetitions to occur immediately adjacent, then instead use

```
     /(.+)\1\1/
```

… as suggested by @Buh Buh — the `\1` vs. `$1` notation may vary, depending on your regexp system.

Comment: It seems op only wants consecutive/adjacent matches.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. \1 is more common than $1. I have updated mine to match.

Comment: +1 for you. I am so close to 1000 happy points now. Can't wait.

Answer (score 0):

it looks weird, but this could be the solution:

```
/000000000|100100100|010010010|001001001|110110110|011011011|101101101|111111111/
```

This contains all possible combinations for three times. So your regular expression will match for these numbers (i.e.):

1. 10010010011
2. 00010010011
3. 10110110110

But not for these:

1. 101010101010
2. 001110111110
3. 111000111000

And it doesn't matter where the sequence appears in the whole string.

Comment: okay, I have read the question again - and I think this is not what you want, cause this regex is for 3*3 pattern. you want n*m pattern.